# Example solutions for PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, examples-counterexamples

$$
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\1}{\mathbf{1}}
\newcommand{\id}{\mathbb{1}}
\newcommand{\allone}{\mathbb{A}}
$$

Which smooth funcion $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ solves the PDE

$$
\tag{1}
\label{PDE}
\text{d}f(x) \cdot x = f(x) + \lambda \,  x \cdot \1
$$

or in coordinates

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \partial_if(x) \, x_i = f(x) + \lambda \, \sum_{i=0}^nx_i
$$

for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$? I denote $\1 = (1, \cdots, 1)$.

Some solutions I found already are

- Any 1-homogeneous function, with $\lambda = 0$, by [Euler's theorem for homogeneous functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function#Euler%27s_homogeneous_function_theorem);
- $f(x) = x \cdot \ln{x} = \sum_{i=0}^n x_i \ln{x_i}$, with $\lambda = 1$

---

To provide some context, this PDE appears in the study of the [Hamiltonian structure](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.5900) of [Riemannian Evolutionary Games](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.09173); more precisely it is the condition that the potential of a Hessian metric should satisfy for the corresponding system to be Hamiltonian with respect to a constant coefficient Poisson structure.

---

**Edit:** I have not been clear in stating the problem. The answer of Sal provides solution $f_{\lambda}(x)$ to $\eqref{PDE}$ for any *fixed* $\lambda$. I am looking for functions $f$ such that there exists $\lambda$ such that $\eqref{PDE}$ holds true. For example it is easy to check that in $n$ dimensions

$$
\tag{2}
\label{f}
f(x) = a Mx \cdot \ln{x} + b \cdot x
$$
admits values of $\lambda$ such that $\eqref{PDE}$ holds true, whenever $M$ is a matrix such that
$$
(Mx) \cdot \1 \text{ is proportional to } x \cdot \1
$$
([see related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4316790/dimension-of-matrix-vector-space) about this space).

Indeed if $f$ is in the form \eqref{f} then
$$
x \cdot df(x) = f(x) + a \,  (Mx) \cdot \1
$$

So the question would now be whether there exists other forms beyond \eqref{f} such that \eqref{PDE} holds true for *some* $\lambda$.

Comment: Have you tried method of characteristics?

Comment: I have absolutely no background in PDEs solving and I'm not familiar with the method of characteristics, but I'll have a look at it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me demonstrate how to solve the specific case $n=2$ using the method of characteristics. The case arbitrary $n$ is below. The PDE for $f(x_1,x_2)$ is

$$\tag{1}
x_1\partial_1f+x_2\partial_2f=f+\lambda (x_1+x_2)
$$

Together with initial condition $f(x_1,g(x_1))=\psi(x_1)$ along some curve in the $x_1,x_2$ plane which is the graph of $x_2=g(x_1)$. Parametrize the characteristics with $z$ and differentiate

$$\tag{2}
\frac{df}{dz}=\frac{dx_1}{dz}\partial_1f+\frac{dx_2}{dz}\partial_2f:=\text{RHS of (1)}
$$

On the characteristic curves we have the following coupled ODEs

$$\tag{3}
\frac{dx_1}{dz}=x_1  \\
\frac{dx_2}{dz}=x_2 \\
\frac{df}{dz}=f+\lambda (x_1+x_2)
$$

We choose $z=0$ along the initial data curve $f(a_1,g(a_1))=\psi(a_1)$. The first two equations in (3) may be integrated directly

$$\tag{4}
x_1(z,a_1)=a_1e^z \\
x_2(z,a_1)=g(a_1)e^z
$$

We can substitute these into the last equation in (3)

$$
\frac{df}{dz}-f=\lambda e^z(a_1+g(a_1))
$$

This is a linear, inhomogeneous, first order equation that we may solve directly (eg. using integrating factor or homogeneous plus particular solution), with the initial condition $f(z=0)=\psi(a_1)$

$$\tag{5}
f(z,a_1)=\psi(a_1)e^z+\lambda z e^z (a_1+g(a_1))
$$

What remains is to invert the co-ordinate transformation defined in (4) back to $x_1,x_2$ from $z,a_1$. For example, if $g(a)=a^2$, then the solution is

$$
f(x_1,x_2)=\frac{x_1^2}{x_2}\psi\left(\frac{x_2}{x_1}\right)+\lambda(x_1+x_2)\ln\left(\frac{x_1^2}{x_2}\right)
$$

Which you can check does solve (1) for arbitrary $\psi$. Now you can generate all kinds of specific solutions by choosing particular forms for $\psi$.

Looking over the calculations, the only change for arbitrary $n$ is the initial condition:
$$
f(x_1,x_2,\dots ,x_{n-1},g)=\psi(x_1,x_2,\dots ,x_{n-1})
$$

Where $g=g(x_1,x_2,\dots ,x_{n-1})$. The co-ordinate transformation in (4) becomes

$$
x_i(z,a_1,\dots,a_{n-1})=a_ie^z \qquad, \qquad i\neq n \\
x_n(z,a_1,\dots,a_{n-1})=g e^z
$$

And the solution is

$$\tag{6}
f(z,a_1,\dots,a_{n-1})=\psi(a_1,\dots,a_{n-1})e^z+\lambda z e^z (a_1+\cdots+a_{n-1}+g)
$$

Where again the solution is to be expressed in the original co-ordinates after inverting the co-ordinate transform. If we *choose* $g=a_1^2$ (for simplicity) then the inversion may be done neatly for arbitrary $n$

$$\tag{7}
e^z=\frac{x_1^2}{x_n} \\
a_i=\frac{x_i x_n}{x_1^2}
$$

Substituting (7) into (6)

$$
f(x)= \frac{x_1^2}{x_n} \psi(a)\big|_{a=a(x)}+\lambda (x_1+\cdots+x_n) \ln\left( \frac{x_1^2}{x_n}\right)
$$

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks! I'm a bit puzzled about the freedom in the choice of $g$. What happens making a different choice? For example $g(a_1) = a_1$ seems to give a degenerate situation.

Comment: @DavideL You're welcome! For the problem to be well-posed, the initial data curve ($z=0$) must not be parallel to the characteristic curves ($a=$constant) at any point. Heuristically, the function data is propagated along characteristic curves, so you can see they'll be a problem if it's ever tangent to the initial data curve. If $g=a_1$ the initial data curve ($z=0$) is the line $x_1=x_2$ and the characteristic curves are $(x_1,x_2)=(a_1e^z,a_1e^z)$ which *are* tangent for fixed $a_1$ and varying $z$