# Dimension of matrix vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

$$
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
$$

Let $M_{n}(\R)$ be the vector space of $n \times n$ real matrices over the reals. For any $x \in \R^n$, denote by $\lvert x \rvert$ the sum over its components:

$$
\lvert x \rvert = \sum_{i = 1}^nx_i
$$
Let
$$S = \{A \in M_{n}(\R) \text{ such that } \lvert Ax \rvert \propto \lvert x \rvert   \}$$

This space is closed under matrix addition and scalar multiplication and contains the zero matrix, so it's a vector subspace of $M_n(\R)$.

**What is its dimension?**

It has to be at least 2, since the identity matrix and the matrix with $1$ in evert entry belong to $S$.

Comment: What does $\lvert Ax \rvert \propto \lvert x \rvert$ mean? Is there a fixed constant of proportionality for each $A$?

Comment: Yes, and I think this is the only possible case: $\lvert Ax \rvert$ is a real valued linear function, so if we demand that $\lvert x \rvert$ factors out, the remaining factor has to be a number by linearity.

Comment: That is true, and if we demanded one constant of proportionality for all of the $A$, then that would only be a vector space if the constant was zero.

Comment: Nice! You may be interested in this related question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4315361/example-solutions-for-pde since this space of matrices appears trying to solve the PDE described there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $A$ there is $a\in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ we have $\mathbf{1}^T(Ax)=a(\mathbf{1}^T x)$, if and only if $A^T \mathbf{1} = a \mathbf{1}$.

So you are asking for the dimension of the space of matrices which have $\mathbf{1}$ as an eigenvector.

If we express any linear transformation in the basis with $\mathbf{1} =e_1$, then the linear transformation has $\mathbf{1}$ as an eigenvector if and only if its matrix representation in that basis has a zero in the first column in every row except the first (it can have any number in the first row, and this number will be the $a$ mentioned above).

So the dimension is $n^2-n+1$